# Place client and server logs from meteor in an external file

Tags: logging, meteor

We have our clients and server running on different machines. We need to place all the logs from each client and server in external files, on respective systems. So that in future, in case of any issues, these logs can be picked from all these machines and provided to us for debugging the same.
But the first step is placing the logs in an external file. Can anyone suggest any package/module for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is popular. I'm not try but I think this is the answer for you : https://meteorhacks.com/logging-support-for-meteor.html.
In that post, you can find some configuration for send log to another logs-server.

Comment: It seems like only a server side logging mechanism.

Comment: Meteor load all package in both client and server. So I think you can use it in client. Or you want use a lightweight js package for logger in client you can use https://github.com/jonnyreeves/js-logger

Comment: But I think you don't need log in client. All error should catch in server and write log in server is enough. In client you only check and push alert message for user

Comment: Ours isn't a usual web application where the user kinda just fills a form and clicks a submit button and in case of errors we just show a message. Ours is a VERY interactive web application. Consider a game. You don't show error message alerts to the user, but you might want to log them in the background.